# Enabling a droppable via a function call

Tags: javascript, jquery

In this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/zyUkd/26/

I am attempting to enable the div "Hello 01" to accept a droppable when I click the button "Add Droppable" . I'm adding the droppable class "todrop" when the button is clicked but when I then drop an item on "Hello 01" the droppable event is not registered ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `.droppable()` on the element in the `addDroppable()` function:

```
var addDrop = $("#adddrophere").droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        alert('dropped here');
    }
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/zyUkd/27/)

Answer (score 0):

call the droppable when the button is clicked

```
$( ".selector" ).droppable();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking to change the class by refering. you have to refer the element.
The working code:

```
function addDroppable() {
       var addDrop = $("div#adddrophere");
    addDrop.addClass("todrop");
    addDrop.removeClass("myDivs");

    //alert(addDrop.text());

}
```